# K-vertices with least distance to subset of other vertices in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science, analysis-of-algorithms

Given an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ where $V=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ denotes the vertices and $E=\{e_1,e_2,...,e_m\}$ denotes edges. Moreover, there exists a nonnegative weight associated with each edge.

We have some arbitrary set of *terminal nodes* denoted by $T$, in which $T \subset V$. For the sake of illustration, let $T=\{v_2,v_4,v_5,v_6\}$. Considering the set $T$, we need to find the $p$ vertices ($p \ll |V|$) from the set $V$ that has the minimum distance from the set $T$.

In other words, let's assume $p=2$. First, we seek to find a vertex from set $V$ that has a minimum distance with respect to edges weight to vertices in set $T$. Second, what is the second minimum vertex from $V$?

•   Are there any well-known problems in graph theory related to what is described?

•   What is the most efficient algorithm to solve this problem?

Note: In more general perspective, is there any efficient algorithm to calculate $K-$Vertex of K-least distance to all other vertices in a sample graph?

Comment: Is your distance from $v$ to the set $T$ the classical distance (the minimum distance to a vertex of $T$), or the sum of distances from $v$ to each vertex of $T$, or something else (total weight of a steiner tree...)? In the first case, you just do a BFS starting from the set $T$.

Comment: @caduk: The distance from $v$ to the set $T$ is the sum of distance from $v$ to each vertex of $T$. I was wondering if I can calculate the sum of distance to each vertex of $T$ for all vertices of the graph. Then, I will go through all vertices and select the vertex with minimum distance calculated for each node. Based on  the number of $p$, I can repeat the selection. What do you think?

Comment: @caduk: It occurred to me that this problem is similar to uniform fault-tolerance K-median problem on the graph. However, k-median problem proved to be NP-Hard. Hence, I am not sure if the previous comment results in polynomial solution for this problem.

Comment: What exactly is your objective function? If we note $d_T(v) = \sum_{t\in T} d(v, t)$ the sum of distances from $v$ to all vertices of $T$, do we need to find a set $P$ such that $|P| = p$ which minimize $\sum_{p\in P} d_T(p)$? Then just compute $d_T(v)$ for each vertex and take the p smaller values. Do we need to minimize $\sum_{t\in T} \min_{p\in P} d(p, t)$ ? Then we can get a polynomial reduction from the dominating set problem.